# unable to access remote database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, windows-authentication

i have changed the connection string to point to a database in the remote server. But when I execute the project the program still points to the local db.

```
<entityFramework>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>


<connectionStrings> 
<add name="TEDALS_Ver01.DAL.TedalsContext" 
  connectionString="Data Source=FE0VMC0643\SQLEXPRESS;
  AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TeDaLSdev.mdf;
  Integrated Security=False" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>
<!--<add
   name="TEDALS_Ver01.DAL.TedalsContext"
   connectionString="Server=FE0VMC0643; Database=TeDaLSdev; "
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->

<!--<add name="TEDALS_Ver01.DAL.TedalsContext"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Server=FE0VMC0643;Data Source=FE0VMC0643;
     Initial Catalog=TeDaLSdev;
     Integrated Security=True;
     Connect Timeout=15;
     Encrypt=False;
     TrustServerCertificate=False;" />-->

</connectionStrings>
```

Comments are the different connection strings i have treid so far. i never had a connections string when I was using the LocalDB.

Constructor for Connection

```
public class TedalsContext : DbContext
{
    public TedalsContext()
        : base("TedalsContext")
    {
        //Database.SetInitializer<TedalsContext>(null);
    }
}
```

i am using SQL Server Express as my database.  I have also tried changing the name of the parameter for `base` in constructor as the name of the Database. But it did not change anything.

I have already tried if I have access to the database through SSMS. I am able to create tables but I am unable to rename the database as such(I do not have access rights to rename the database TeDalSdev).

Are there any other work around i could try? Should the name of the remote database and the local database should be the same to avoid changing a lot of code?

UPDATE

Controller

```
public class LsystemFamiliesController : Controller
{
    private TedalsContext db = new TedalsContext();
    //Code goes here
}
```

Comment: call base with base("TEDALS_Ver01.DAL.TedalsContext") ? In the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx#Connection) it says EF will get the connection string differently for code first and designer generated contexts..

Comment: But independently, the name you pass to the DBContext constructor whould be the name of the connection string. You are passing TedalsContext only, which does not exist in your configuration file as it seems.

Comment: See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674) too

Comment: @OguzOzgul:  Now i have added a new db in the server with exactly the same name as my localdb. i really do not understand the different parameters int he connection string. So i have to go with the trial and error to get it somehow working.

Comment: db name is not the issue here don't you see? The name of the connection string "TedalsContext" does not match to any connection string in the configuration file. Try base("TEDALS_Ver01.DAL.TedalsContext") ?

Comment: Added that. Changed the connection string to exactly what is there in the properties of the database. Still it accesses the local db.

Comment: Can you show me the first part of your program that accesses the database? Can you also check that all DB access is done through Entity Framework context? It may be that you have some low level access such as using a SqlConnection directly.

Comment: i have no places where a connection to the database is established in the program. All the controllers access the data via the entity framework context. But i will add first part of code in a controller

Comment: Why is the question being downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added a connection string from a web config file of one of my projects and all the fields that (should) be checked. This is within the `<connectionStrings>` tags. You need to make it your default connection and you can only have one connection string as the default connection.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    connectionString="Data Source=Providedbyhost;integrated 
    security=false;Initial Catalog=DB_Name;User Id=UserId;Password=password;
    Trusted_Connection=false; TrustServerCertificate=true;
    Encrypt=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Where you have your DB Context:

```
public TedalsContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
```

Switch everything to DefaultConnection, until you get it working, then you can focus on changing names. Comment out your local db connection strings. Even remove it from the project if you need to (and save it elsewhere), while you are testing this.

I've also added a screen shot of the my folder directory, to show which web config folder I am modifying. See it's highlighted in blue.

[image]

Also this screen shot shows you where to navigate to test your connection string within VS.

[image]

I suggest you look here:

[How to: Access SQL Server Using Windows Integrated Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx)

[What will be the connectionstring for mssql windows authentication](http://forums.asp.net/t/1656040.aspx?What%20will%20be%20the%20connectionstring%20for%20mssql%20windows%20authentication)

and this:

[Connection string using Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270082/connection-string-using-windows-authentication)

As I suggested in the discussion. I recommend also contacting web hosting provider, as I have had this problem where it will not connect and it's been a problem at the hosting end.

If you need more help, shout out.

Comment: i am using windows authentication. So i can skip the username and password fields??

Comment: And i have the connection active in my server explorer. But still the data that is being fetched from the local db.

Comment: so now i have changed the connection exactly as yours: with details about my server and db;removed username and password, still no changes. is there something that i will need to change in the entity framework section?

Comment: Yes. I have done that as well. No changes. I am editing the config file which is in the root directory. And thanks for helping.

Comment: I am also modifying the  same config file. yes it annoying because i have been trying this since thursday. and havent found anything.

Comment: I have also disconnected the local server. And in the server explorer now i do not find the connected server.

Comment: i only find in the server default connection and in the properties the name of the server is `TedalsContext`. is it the expected behaviour?

Comment: Your answer led me to the right direction. With an additional line in my controller it worked perfectly. i had to add `base("name=TedalsContext")`. Now it is working.. thanks a lot.. reallyy a lot.. :) :) :)

Comment: No. With default connection laso it will work. But i have to add the attribute `name` in base. But your links really helped a lot.. And i could understand that the database was loaded with ur screenshots..

Answer (score 0):

Under your TedalsContext constructor, use `: base(connectionStringName)`.

Otherwise, the context will treat it as code first and create a TedalContext inside your SQLExpress Local DB.

```
public class TedalsContext : DbContext
{
    public TedalsContext()
        : base("TEDALS_Ver01.DAL.TedalsContext")
    {
        //Database.SetInitializer<TedalsContext>(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that as well. Check the comments in the question. @Oguz has already suggested that..

Comment: Have you tried inserting the entire connectionstring into the `base()`?

Comment: yes. Based on other answer now i have changed my base to default connection