# MVC Controllers - Connection String / associations - No Connection String could be found in the application config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, connection-string

Please excuse me is this is a noob question. I have a MVC project with a number of EF Database first models. When I created them some were created with new connection strings.

I have tried to clean up the project web.config file and commented out the duplicated connection strings,

```
    <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=........... />
<add name="DB_A09819_ProductsEntities" connectionString="metadata=........... />
<add name="DB_A09819_PowerDB001Entities" connectionString="metadata=........... />
<!--  
  <add name="DB_A09819_ProductsEntities_IntranetDownload" connectionString="metadata........... />
  <add name="DB_A09819_ProductsPricing" connectionString="metadata=........... />
  <add name="DB_A09819_ProductsProjectProposal" connectionString="metadata=.......... />
<add name="DB_A09819_ProductsProposalSystem"    connectionString="metadata=........... />
 -->

</connectionStrings>
```

I had thought that MVC would have picked up on the changes and raised errors, however with these changes the project builds and runs on development server.

When I try to add a controller I now get an error that the

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Error

There was an error running the selected code generator:

'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'web...............t'. 
No connection string named 'DB_A09819_..........' 
could be found in the application config file.'
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I would like to change the associations and fix the connection string to have a single connection to each of the databases.

There are a number of  [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622408/no-connection-string-named-myentities-could-be-found-in-the-application-config) where the solution is to add a connection string, I am trying to clean up my code and remove duplicate connection strings.

How do I change the association to the connection string in the Model and the controllers to ensure that it will run when deployed ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790325/entityframework-where-is-the-connection-string

Comment: I have tried to clean and re-build the project and it still works with the connection string commented out.

Comment: Delete the files in the BIN directory, after rebuilding I received a run-time error. Still not able to find the cross references to the connection strings.

Comment: Are you using Entity framework?

Comment: I am using EF Database first, thank you Adesh M.

Comment: Have you used the Find option to search the Entire Solution for DB_A09819?